# Issues with CSS transitions on Next.js project

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-transitions

I'm working on a project in Next.js (React) for the first time. It's a static site (only frontend).
Somehow I run into lots of problems related to the CSS transitions and I can't catch what am I missing.

When using some ready components, for example Modal from react-bootstrap, the transition seems to be working on Modal show, but not on hide. Transitions from Accordion, from the same module, work fine, but didn't work from other Accordion component I tried before that.

I will put some code here, but I have a filling, that there is some fundamental css/js related topic that I don't understand fully, but my searches didn't bring me the answer yet.

Here is the sample of the component, the related CSS is the default bootstrap-css (for the sake of simplicity):

**Nav.tsx**

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import navStyles from '../styles/Nav.module.css'
import homeStyles from "../styles/Home.module.css"
import {useState} from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/cjs/Modal"
import Button from "react-bootstrap/cjs/Button";

const MyVerticallyCenteredModal = (props) => {
    return (
        <Modal
            {...props}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
        >
            <Modal.Header>
                <Button onClick={props.onHide}>X</Button>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <p style={{color: "white"}}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
                    elit. Aliquid at consequuntur cum ducimus enim fuga hic laudantium magni
                    maiores, molestias nesciunt nihil nisi nostrum pariatur perspiciatis rem rerum
                    suscipit, unde?</p>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    );
}

const Nav = () => {

    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);

    const NavComp = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <div className={navStyles.wrapper}>
                    <div className={`${homeStyles.home} ${homeStyles.mobile}`}>
                        <div className={navStyles.footer}>

                            <button
                                className={`${navStyles.footerBtn}`}
                                onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}
                                style={{borderLeft: "1px rgba(70,70,70,0.5) solid"}}
                            >
                                Contact
                            </button>
                            <MyVerticallyCenteredModal
                                show={modalShow}
                                onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }

    return (
        <nav className={navStyles.nav}>
            <div className={navStyles.container}>
                <div className={navStyles.logo}>
                    <Link href='/'>
                        <div>
                            <p className={navStyles.kaveem}>KAVEEM</p>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <NavComp/>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Nav;
```

Comment: How did you install react-bootstrap and what version it it? I can't find any recent import examples involving that "cjs"/CommonJS import except in a very old 0.4.0 README, have you given the suggested way a go? ( import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'; )

Comment: I did the usual "npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap".
The version is 1.5.2. I will try to change it like you said, thank you.
The thing is, it happens with other components too. 
For example CSSTransition, some of the pages are transitioned and some not. I guess it related to some CSS in those pages, but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Tried it that way, same effect: transition on "in" is working, on "out", not.